# Is it possible to have windows integrated and forms auth on the same web app (same url)?

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Basically I want to build a web app that will try windows authentication and if authentication fails then will provide the user with a login form ?

I do not want to have different web apps for different authentication modes.

Is this possible ? Did I missed some points about this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could go into your IIS Error Pages settings and change the various target pages for the 401 error to point to a Windows Forms login page. That way, then the user bails out/fails for the three requested authentication attempts it redirects to another page.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up more than one virtual directory that points to the same folder.  One vdir uses forms auth and the other using integrated.